# How to stop recording on blur event page in rrweb.io record and change timestamp when user return

Tags: javascript, function, sorting, date, timestamp

I am use [Rrweb.io](https://www.rrweb.io/)
I'm trying not to show inactive user actions in the player when he left the page, and when he returned, start recording again!

Actual problem:
I know how to not recording events when user is leave page, but in events that i sent to backend, there have a field in object timestamp which takes a snapshot of the time of the event.
And when i recording this session in rrweb.player i see that when i not was active in page like user, the player show me just cursor on one position before i'm return in page.
Maybe in library have some methods that can configure recording

---

I use:

```
"rrweb": "^0.9.7" - in script

"rrweb": "^0.9.7",
"rrweb-player": "^0.6.2" - for player
```

Here init method:

```
   initRecord(){
    const _self = this
    this.record = rrweb.record({
     emit(event) {
      _self.events.push(event)
     },
   })
  this.interval.push(setInterval(() => {
    if(!this.errorRequest){
      self.saveRecord()
    }
  }, INTERVAL_NUMBER * 1000))
```

Here saveRecord method:

```
async saveRecord(){
const _self = this
const params = this.getParams()

this.events = []

await saveRecord({ params })
  .then((response) => {
    return response
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    this.errorRequest = true
    clearInterval(this.interval)
    console.error(error);
    });
```

Here method that prepare params:

```
getParams(isLarge) {
 const screenWidth = window.screen.width
 const screenHeight = window.screen.height
 const exitPage = window.location.pathname
 const events = this.secureText(this.events)
 let duration = 0
return {
 screenWidth,
 screenHeight,
 exitPage,
 events,
 duration
}
```

Comment: add some of your code snippets for better clarity to problem your facing

Comment: Thanks Riaz, added!

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but rrweb-player has a toggle to skip the in-active events

Comment: @Omair Nabiel - it is correct.
For example, we are writing a script that records activity on the web page, and we know that we have the opportunity to toggle inactive actions of users in the player.
In that all actions that I wrote upper I find that users can switch the tab in the browser and our script still recording events. 
And after in admin panel with showing all records of that page. I see that the user was on page 1 hour, but for example, 30 mins of that 1 hours record, the user switched tab in the browser not was active actually

Comment: Yea that I know. You cannot prevent that that's because each event has timestamp attached to it and the total time is calculated from the difference of first event's timestamp to the last event's timestamp. The thing is the video when playing will skip the inactive and the playtime will be 30mins although the time says 1 hour. Moreover It would be better if the player showed some indication on the progress bar for the inactive time, so anyone watching the video can skip manually the inactive part. I created a issue for that on the repo here https://github.com/rrweb-io/rrweb/issues/621

Comment: @OmairNabiel thank you!
I think this is the better way for solving this problem.